# Assigning updated value to $_SESSION array

Tags: php, arrays

Can someone tell me why the $_SESSION array is not getting modified by the code below.  The object is to put the date in DoNotShipBefore of each record. It is obviously putting the value somewhere as the output of $Row['DoNotShipBefore'] shows the correct date.  But, when the loop is done, it doesn't appear to have taken.

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION[cart_array]);
foreach($_SESSION[cart_array] as $Row) {        

      $Row['DoNotShipBefore'] = date("m/d/Y") ;
      echo "<br>New Value of DoNotShipBefore (From cart_array): ". $Row['DoNotShipBefore'] ;

}
print "<br><br>";
print_r($_SESSION[cart_array]);
die();
```

Output follows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [groupId] => 26141 [DoNotShipBefore] => 10/01/2017)) 

New Value of DoNotShipBefore (From cart_array): 07/06/2017

Array ( [0] => Array ( [groupId] => 26141  [DoNotShipBefore] => 10/01/2017))

// Should be (or what I want is):
Array ( [0] => Array ( [groupId] => 26141  [DoNotShipBefore] => 07/06/2017))
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to address Arrays within the SESSION, so would really appreciate any help.

Comment: change this line `foreach($_SESSION[cart_array] as $Row) {` to `foreach($_SESSION[cart_array] as &$Row) {`

Comment: You are not updating $_SESSION array. Only update $row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except when the value is an object, when you assign a variable it makes a copy of the value (internally it uses copy-on-write for efficiency). So `$Row` is a copy of the row in `$_SESSION`. You're modifying that copy, not the original array.

You can use a reference variable to make it refer to the original array, by putting `&` before the variable.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as &$Row) {
```

Comment: Thank you.  Still struggling with arrays...thanks for your solution and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What is `cart_array`? Maybe you should use `$_SESSION['cart_array']`? Any PHP notice?

Comment: If there's no constant with that name, PHP automatically converts it to a string literal, and prints a notice if you have warnings enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code that is actually assigning any values in the session array.

```
$_SESSION['some_var'] = "Some Value";
```

But you're not doing that so the session you have remains untouched.